# Why can't hadoop find class of RackAareness?

Tags: java, hadoop

I have configured `net.topology.node.switch.mapping.impl` property in core-site.xml.The value of class is `com.learning.rackawareness.RackAwareness`. I already packaged the class to be jar and put it up Linux in hadoop path of `/opt/modules/hadoop-2.7.2/share/hadoop/common/lib`.

Then I used `start-dfs.sh`, Namenode failed.

where should I do to put the jar?

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.learning.rackawareness.RackAwareness not found
>       at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2227)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.DatanodeManager.(DatanodeManager.java:208)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.(BlockManager.java:268)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.(FSNamesystem.java:737)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.initialize(SecondaryNameNode.java:246)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.(SecondaryNameNode.java:192)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.main(SecondaryNameNode.java:671)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class >com.learning.rackawareness.RackAwareness not found
>       at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2219)
>       ... 6 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class >com.learning.rackawareness.RackAwareness not found
>       at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
>       ... 7 more
>   2019-10-07 15:23:41,958 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Stopping services started for active state
>   2019-10-07 15:23:41,970 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:

Comment: check your Hadoop classpath: `bin/hadoop classpath`

Comment: I already checked Hadoop classpath. The classpath have contained the path of  /opt/modules/hadoop-2.7.2/share/hadoop/common/lib.But it have been still incorrect.Then I tried to add the path of rack.jar to hadoop-env.sh by HADOOP_CLASSPATH.But it have been incorrect.What's the problem?