# Why can't hadoop load the class?

Tags: java, hadoop

I configured a RackAareness class in core-site.xml.Then I configured a classpath which it contains RackAreness class in hadoop-env.sh. Like this:export HADOOP_CLASSPATH="/opt/modules/hadoop-2.7.2/lib/rack.jar"

I can see the classpath if I use command:hadoop classpath.

Then I started hdfs but the namenode was exited.The error was logged.

What should I do?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class >com.learning.rackawareness.RackAwareness not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.DatanodeManager.<init>(DatanodeManager.java:208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.<init>(BlockManager.java:268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:737)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.initialize(SecondaryNameNode.java:246)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.<init>(SecondaryNameNode.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.main(SecondaryNameNode.java:671)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class >com.learning.rackawareness.RackAwareness not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2219)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class >com.learning.rackawareness.RackAwareness not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't hadoop find class of RackAareness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58279611/why-cant-hadoop-find-class-of-rackaareness)

Comment: but it's not classpath problem.